# Problema com Fetch e Json no Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema com Fetch Javascript

```js
let url = "https://www.teste.com.br/ws"



fetch(url,{
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   
}).then(function(response){
    response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

No Console aparece o erro ( Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at fetch.js:10
que é a linha " response.json().then(function(data) { "
Alguem pode me ajudar a resolver isso ?

Agradeço.

Comment: Tem uns erros de sintaxe no código, por exemplo `let url = "let url = "https://www.teste.com.br/ws"`

Comment: Aqui também: `});"`

Comment: arrumei a questão do let url. Isso aconteceu por que copiei errado.

Comment: O problema deve ser no retorno, porque o código em si tá funcionando normal.

Comment: sobre o site, eu escrevi um site qualquer pois o webservice é da empresa.

Comment: Mas ainda ficou um erro na linha `});"` (aspas duplas errada).

Comment: Ah sim... testei aqui e mesmo com uma URL qualquer não apresenta o erro mencionado.

Comment: pois é cara, funciona mesmo mas não me retorna o json

Comment: aparece esse erro Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at fetch.js:10

Comment: Vc quer fazer 2 fetchs?

Comment: já removi o que estava duplicado

Comment: deve ser outra coisa, porque o código não retorna nenhum erro.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/teste.php) e abre o console. Veja tb no código-fonte o script indentado certinho. Tá tudo blz.

Comment: Remova `mode: 'no-cors'` das opções e veja o que acontece!